# Disable TypeScript Inline for an individual file

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have TS running with errors that I would like to ignore, compile, but when using

`/* tslint:disable */`

it still runs when running my build.

```
hutber@hutber:/var/www/bp/frontend$ git commit -m"feat: add basic foundations for theme & breadcrums"
husky > pre-commit (node v14.14.0)
$ tsc
components/Layouts/Breadcrums/index.tsx:17:13 - error TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'HTMLCollection'.

17             {a}
               ~~~
```

Comment: Can you show the code? it seems that you are trying to assign String to HTMLCollection. incomponents/Layouts/Breadcrums/index.tsx:17:13

Comment: I'd just like to point out that the correct spelling is `Breadcrumbs`, just FYI.

Comment: Are you trying to disable tslint (the linter rules) or tsc (type checking)?

Comment: @HasipTimurtas of course, I will update the question. However, I am not looking for a fix on the TS side of things, I would just like to know how to turn off TS for one file.

Comment: Ahh @Bergi I think you have nailed the problem. I am trying to turn off TSC :D thank you

Comment: Please post your `tsconfig`

Comment: You probably want to check to make sure that this is not a real problem. If this coes *does* work, you can use a typecast or other TypeScript code and *not* disable type checking on the entire file. If you are going to do that, why use TypeScript for this file at all?

Comment: The question says disable `TypeScript` but your first line mentions tslint? Please update the question, it's unclear what you are trying to do. If you really want to disable type checking in one place, just cast the value using `as unknown as CorrectType`, or just use `any`

Answer (score 1):

In your `tslint.json`, you could try excluding the file:

```
{
  "extends": "tslint:latest",
  "linterOptions": {
      "exclude": [
          "bin",
          "<path to your excluded file here>"
      ]
  }
}
```

or adding your file to `.eslintignore`, if you have that instead.

Comment: Thank you, but I would like to do this inline.

Answer (score 1):

I think TSLint is deprecated and one needs to use e.g. `// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/<type of error>`. However, I'm not fully aware of your configuration, so this might need to fine tuning.